# Detect the end of a Spotify track with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify, playback

I'm writing an Applescript that displays a notification with the name, album, and artist of the current  Spotify track. Yes, I'm aware there is already an app that does this, but even with the latest version, it's very buggy and behaves erratically.

So far, I have a good little script. Here it is:

```
repeat until application "Spotify" is not running
    tell application "Spotify"
        set theSong to name of current track
        set theAlbum to album of current track
        set theArtist to artist of current track
        set theTime to player position
        set theDuration to duration of current track
    end tell


    (* This sets the amount of delay to the length of the song minus the current place in the song, which leaves us with the amount of time left until the next song plays.*)
    set delayTime to theDuration - theTime + 0.5

    tell application "Spotify"
        if player state is playing then
            display notification theArtist with title theSong subtitle theAlbum
        end if

        delay delayTime

    end tell
end repeat
```

Basically, the problem with this is if I pause or change the track, delay stays the same and thus doesn't display the notification when the song starts.

I used delay in this script because I don't really know a better way of checking for the end of a track. Is there any Applescript event for the end of a song (or the beginning of a new one?)

Thanks.

P.S., If this question is too complicated, feel free to ask more.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that `duration of current track` seems to be returning milliseconds instead of seconds?  The AppleScript docs say "duration (integer, r/o) : The length of the track in seconds.", but I'm getting a value of 76553 for a 1:19 track.

Comment: @bonh, and it's still not fixed as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop to check the current track, exit the loop when the song change

```
repeat until application "Spotify" is not running
    tell application "Spotify"
        set theSong to name of current track
        set theAlbum to album of current track
        set theArtist to artist of current track
        set thisTrack to current track
        if player state is playing then
            display notification theArtist with title theSong subtitle theAlbum
            repeat until thisTrack is current track
                delay 3
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks man! I actually figured out how to do this on my own but I forgot mark this question as answered. But yeah, If I hadn't figured this out, this would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you post what your answer was? Was it the same as this one?